# Simple way to manage authentication in WCF REST service (like an OAuth light)?

Tags: .net, wcf, oauth

I have a REST-based WCF web service that is currently protected with basic authentication. It's currently only accepting one userID/password combination since I'm still in testing phase.
That combination is simply stored in my `web.config` for now.

My web service is not intended, at least for the foreseeable future, to be called by more than a handful of clients and does not have the concept of different scopes (either you can call it  with full privileges or you can't call it at all).

For those reasons, I am hesitant to implement a full-blown OAuth Provider the way I've seen it described (e.g. [here](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2011/06/what-is-2-legged-oauth.html)) because it just seems overly complicated to implement for what I need.

I've seen OAuth providers done (by Yelp's API for instance) in a much simpler way where the provider supplies credentials to the consumer "off-line" and the consumer just uses those credentials to generate an "OAuth-compliant" request.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find any details on how to do that, only the typical 2 or 3-legged OAuth.

Any good suggestions?